# Can't get data in laravel controller that sent from ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, eloquent

I have a route,

```
Route::post('/shop', 'ShopController@index');
Route::resource('/shop', 'ShopController')->parameters(['shop' => 'slug']);
```

I want to filter products via price range.

this is my :

```
filter_data();
        var sliderrange = $('#slider-range');
        var amountprice = $('#amount');
        function filter_data() {
            var  min_price = $("#min_price").val();
            var  max_price = $("#max_price").val();
            console.log(min_price);
            $.ajax({ url:"/shop", method:"GET",
                data:{ min_price:min_price, max_price:max_price,},
                success:function (data) { },
            });
        };
```

and this is the controller:

```
    public function index(Request $request)
{
    $min = $request->input('min_price');
    $max = $request->input('max_price');

    return view('front.pages.shop', ['products' => Product::where('status', 1)->whereBetween('price', ['min', 'max'])->latest()->paginate(15)]);
}
```

Comment: Can you please make the question more specififc? What does the controller actually do?

Comment: see my updated snipts please

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Does the get request work? Is laravel returning the incorract data? Pease clarify the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the problem is that the controller isnt returning the correct data (As far as i can tell.)

The first step in debugging such a issue is checking if the parameter youre using to query are actually filled.

This can be done like this:
`dd($min, $max)`

If the output of the dd function shows empty values the issue is withtin the ajax request. 
If they are set you want to do the following:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $min = $request->input('min_price');
    $max = $request->input('max_price');

    $products = Product::where('status', 1)->whereBetween('price', ['min', 'max'])->latest()->paginate(15);
    dd($products);

    return view('front.pages.shop', ['products' => $products]);
}
```

Place your products in a variable and run the dd() function with the variable to see if you have data. When done debugging remove the dd() function.

If you have data the problem might be somewhere else.

Note: 
If you want to get data you should actually use the GET method for the route instead of using the POST method.

Example:

```
Route::get('/shop', 'ShopController@index');
```

I hope this is a little push in the right direction, try debugging step by step to find the exact point where there might be a issue.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the error message you're receiving in the browser?

If the problem is related to CORS and you're using Laravel 7 you should update the `config/cors.php` file so that it works with your project. (eg setting `'allowed_origins' => ['*']`).

See [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#cors) for details.

Comment: there is no error showing exactly but no products are showing also.if i replace all code in my controller with $data = $request->all();
        print_r($data);
this is renderd an empty array()

Comment: I see. Another issue could be the order how you've defined your routes. A `Route::resource()` generates a ton of additional routes and probably overwrite your standalone `Route::post('/shop', 'ShopController@index');`.


In addition it's a bit confusing to me, which route should do what. You have a POST route "/shop" which uses the `index`-method, but you're calling the /shop URL with AJAX with GET and not POST.

Comment: there is no file called cors.php in may config folder, i am using laravel 6.18

Comment: ok i am updating my code in ajax with URL POST but reasult is same no changed happed @stefanzweifel

Comment: @AbuBasedJibon You're not posting to ajax, you want to GET the data. Just rewrite the route

Comment: Can you write it for me @Collin

Comment: @AbuBasedJibon Take a look at my awnser